# Handling variables across multiple UIs in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I have a following scenario:

I have two forms (UI). From the first UI, user is navigated to the second one.
In the second UI, I have a label and a button. When user presses the button, the text of label is increased (from 1,2,3, and so on.)

I would like to achieve this by adding a integer variable whose value is 0 initially. When I press the button, I will increase the integer value by 1 and set the integer text in the label.

This logic may make no sense but I am trying out just to be clear on concept.

My question is, where should i keep this variable. Usually, we have separate classes for each UIs. On each UI, we declare necessary variables which are private and not visible to other classes and use that variable within that UI class.

But in code name one, the structure seem to be different. We have a class StateMachine, which handles all the things of all the UIs (like click event, page load event, etc.). It seems we do not have any privacy between the UIs.

Is there any specific way that I can use different classes for each UIs?

Answer (score 1):

The StateMachine is just the GUI Builder way, you can also create a "manual" project and code all the UI by yourself.

Comment: Also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/JbXgwUhudtM/Nwl4zm-eObcJ